# how debug a dll in delphi7 with win 7 x64 IS POSSIBLE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I try to debug a COM+ DLL in Delphi 7 in a Win7 environment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a [work around](http://anotherlab.rajapet.net/2009/08/work-around-for-delphi-20072009-with.html).

Comment: this work around works for delphi2007 but not for delphi7 ,i can debug a program exe , but i can't debug a dll component...  
tks for reply

Answer (score 1):

1 unregister from Com+ the dll 
2 run as administrator in  cmd : regsvr32.exe  
3 Make a break point 
4 In Delphi 7 Run -> Parameters : Host Application : Exe Application that use the interface dll

so the step 2 is the key ...

Answer (score 1):

If it is mostly the debugging you are concerned about, not necessarily debugging in Windows 7 64, you could set up a virtual computer running Windows 7 32 bit, or, since you seem happy with older technologies, drop back to XP.  You'll need to set up your development environment there, but at least you'll have a full running virtual machine that you can back up or move if you want to.